# eigenvalues and eigenvectors scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I was wondering which method does `[scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs][1]` actually implement to calculate the first k eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Eigenvalue_algorithms but which one is actually implemented.

Comment: It is always helpful to check the documentary first. If this does not help, you could review the source code yourself to find out which method is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick look in the [scipy documentary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) yields:

> This function is a wrapper to the ARPACK [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) SNEUPD, DNEUPD, CNEUPD, ZNEUPD, functions which use the Implicitly Restarted Arnoldi Method to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors